Deflection of light in linearised gravity
In Sean Carroll’s book, section 7.3, he uses the linearised metric to find the deflection of light around a mass $M$. But a mass $M$ has no energy density around it, so $T_{uv}$ is zero everywhere outside, yet Carroll takes it to be $\rho$, saying that we model it using dust. So are we just saying that the effect due to the mass is going to be similar to that of plain dust everywhere near?

He uses dust as a general case, and he chooses dust so he can use a simple scalar density in the stress-energy tensor. But when he specifically addresses light deflection by a star he uses a point mass instead.

He doesnt mention that anywhere in the text though. And how can he use this metric for a point mass? There is no energy outside the mass right?

Page 291 between equations 7.78 and 7.79 he specifically states he is using a point mass, and in the linearised approximation the scalar field $\phi$ becomes the Newtonian 1/r potential.

Thank you for pointing it out. But how can we use the metric which is intended for dust, for this situation?

The metric is derived, assuming some  ρ, it may or may not be 0. Now, if  ρ=0, then the metric component needs to satisfy the laplacian. The laplacian equation can have a trivial solution or the newtonian potential as an answer. Now, we already know from the weak field metric that the h00 term needs to be related to the newtonian gravitational potential, so we can see that we have to use the 1/r solution of the laplacian.
